# JQuery, PHP, MYSQL, DataTable unable to Search

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, datatable

I'm trying to get DataTable to work with INNER JOIN MYSQL QUERY and I made it, but I've found a problem with Searching in form.

The error Says : DataTables warning: table id=material_used - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Well, here's my code :

index.html

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" id="material_used" class="display" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th><div align="center"><font size="2">Date</font></div></th>
        <th><div align="center"><font size="2">Matl Code</font></div></th>
        <th><div align="center"><font size="2">Name</font></div></th>
        <th><div align="center"><font size="2">Spesification</font></div></th>
        <th><div align="center"><font size="2">Qty</font></div></th>
        <th><div align="center"><font size="2">Note</font></div></th>
        <th><div align="center"><font size="2">Reg. No</font></div></th>
        <th><div align="center"><font size="2">WO / Sheet</font></div></th>
        <th><div align="center"><font size="2">Action</font></div></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <th><div align="center"><font size="2">Date</font></div></th>
        <th><div align="center"><font size="2">Matl Code</font></div></th>
        <th><div align="center"><font size="2">Name</font></div></th>
        <th><div align="center"><font size="2">Spesification</font></div></th>
        <th><div align="center"><font size="2">Qty</font></div></th>
        <th><div align="center"><font size="2">Note</font></div></th>
        <th><div align="center"><font size="2">Reg. No</font></div></th>
        <th><div align="center"><font size="2">WO / Sheet</font></div></th>
        <th><div align="center"><font size="2">Action</font></div></th>
    </tfoot>
    
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getWOandSheet(data, type, dataToSet) {
    return data.work_order + " / " + data.sheet_number;
}
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#material_used').DataTable({

            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "bDestroy": true,
            "deferRender": true,

            "columns": [
                {"data": "date"},
                {"data": "material_code"},
                {"data": "name"},
                {"data": "specs"},
                {"data": "qty_act"},
                {"data": "note_act"},
                {"data": "reg_no"},
                {"data": getWOandSheet},
                { "mData": null , //its null here because history column will contain the mRender
                "mRender" : function ( data, type, full ) {
                    return '<a href="edit_material_used.php?cc='+data.code+'">Edit</a> / <a href="delete_mat_used.php?cc='+data.code+'">Delete</a>';}
                }
            ],
            "ajax": {
                url: 'process.php',
                type: 'POST'
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
```

process.php

```html
<?php
/*
 * For more details
 * please check official documentation of DataTables  https://datatables.net/manual/server-side
 * Coded by charaf JRA
 * RefreshMyMind.com
 */

/* IF Query comes from DataTables do the following */
if (!empty($_POST) ) {

    /*
     * Database Configuration and Connection using mysqli
     */

    define("HOST", "localhost");
    define("USER", "root");
    define("PASSWORD", "");
    define("DB", "kdm");
    define("MyTable", "mat_used_master_data");

    $connection = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DB) OR DIE("Impossible to access to DB : " . mysqli_connect_error());

    /* END DB Config and connection */

    /*
     * @param (string) SQL Query
     * @return multidim array containing data array(array('column1'=>value2,'column2'=>value2...))
     *
     */
    function getData($sql){
        global $connection ;//we use connection already opened
        $query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) OR DIE ("Can't get Data from DB , check your SQL Query " );
        $data = array();
        foreach ($query as $row ) {
            $data[] = $row ;
        }
        return $data;
    }

    /* Useful $_POST Variables coming from the plugin */
    $draw = $_POST["draw"];//counter used by DataTables to ensure that the Ajax returns from server-side processing requests are drawn in sequence by DataTables
    $orderByColumnIndex  = $_POST['order'][0]['column'];// index of the sorting column (0 index based - i.e. 0 is the first record)
    $orderBy = $_POST['columns'][$orderByColumnIndex]['data'];//Get name of the sorting column from its index
    $orderType = $_POST['order'][0]['dir']; // ASC or DESC
    $start  = $_POST["start"];//Paging first record indicator.
    $length = $_POST['length'];//Number of records that the table can display in the current draw
    /* END of POST variables */

    $recordsTotal = count(getData("SELECT * FROM ".MyTable));

    /* SEARCH CASE : Filtered data */
    if(!empty($_POST['search']['value'])){

        /* WHERE Clause for searching */
        for($i=0 ; $i<count($_POST['columns']);$i++){
            $column = $_POST['columns'][$i]['data'];//we get the name of each column using its index from POST request
            $where[]="$column like '%".$_POST['search']['value']."%'";
        }
        $where = "WHERE ".implode(" OR " , $where);// id like '%searchValue%' or name like '%searchValue%' ....
        /* End WHERE */

        $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM %s %s", MyTable , $where);//Search query without limit clause (No pagination)

        $recordsFiltered = count(getData($sql));//Count of search result

        /* SQL Query for search with limit and orderBy clauses*/
        $sql = sprintf("SELECT a.code, a.date, a.material_code, b.name, b.specs, a.qty_act, a.note_act, a.reg_no, a.work_order, a.sheet_number FROM mat_used_master_data = a INNER JOIN material_tools_master_data = b ON a.material_code = b.material_code ORDER BY %s %s limit %d , %d ", $where ,$orderBy, $orderType ,$start,$length  );
        $data = getData($sql);
    }
    /* END SEARCH */
    else {
        $sql = sprintf("SELECT a.code, a.date, a.material_code, b.name, b.specs, a.qty_act, a.note_act, a.reg_no, a.work_order, a.sheet_number FROM mat_used_master_data = a INNER JOIN material_tools_master_data = b ON a.material_code = b.material_code ORDER BY %s %s limit %d , %d " ,$orderBy,$orderType ,$start , $length);
        $data = getData($sql);

        $recordsFiltered = $recordsTotal;
    }

    /* Response to client before JSON encoding */
    $response = array(
        "draw" => intval($draw),
        "recordsTotal" => $recordsTotal,
        "recordsFiltered" => $recordsFiltered,
        "data" => $data
    );

    echo json_encode($response);

} else {
    echo "NO POST Query from DataTable";
}
?>
```

So, here's the JSON result after the page loaded :

```js
{draw: 1, recordsTotal: 3578, recordsFiltered: 3578,…}
data
:
[{code: "1", date: "2016-01-04", material_code: "K0000285", name: "Cutting Wheel",…},…]
draw
:
1
recordsFiltered
:
3578
recordsTotal
:
3578

{"draw":1,"recordsTotal":3578,"recordsFiltered":3578,"data":[{"code":"1","date":"2016-01-04","material_code":"K0000285","name":"Cutting Wheel","specs":"Nippon Resibon-A30P BF@25EA","qty_act":"5","note_act":null,"reg_no":"OW001","work_order":"Non Work Order","sheet_number":null},{"code":"2","date":"2016-01-04","material_code":"K0000371","name":"Electrode  ROD (Stick)","specs":"niko steel","qty_act":"20","note_act":null,"reg_no":"OW001","work_order":"Non Work Order","sheet_number":null},{"code":"3","date":"2016-01-04","material_code":"K0000502","name":"Grinding Wheel","specs":"Brand: Ultra","qty_act":"15","note_act":null,"reg_no":"OW001","work_order":"Non Work Order","sheet_number":null},{"code":"4","date":"2016-01-04","material_code":"K0000543","name":null,"specs":null,"qty_act":"3","note_act":null,"reg_no":"OW001","work_order":"Non Work Order","sheet_number":null},{"code":"5","date":"2016-01-07","material_code":"K0000285","name":"Cutting Wheel","specs":"Nippon Resibon-A30P BF@25EA","qty_act":"3","note_act":null,"reg_no":"OW001","work_order":"Non Work Order","sheet_number":null},{"code":"6","date":"2016-01-07","material_code":"K0000286","name":"Cutting Wheel","specs":"Brand : Ultra","qty_act":"10","note_act":null,"reg_no":"OW001","work_order":"Non Work Order","sheet_number":null},{"code":"7","date":"2016-01-07","material_code":"K0000502","name":"Grinding Wheel","specs":"Brand: Ultra","qty_act":"10","note_act":null,"reg_no":"OW001","work_order":"Non Work Order","sheet_number":null},{"code":"8","date":"2016-01-07","material_code":"K0000851","name":"Paint DASAR ( EPOXY )","specs":"KANZEI","qty_act":"20","note_act":null,"reg_no":"OW001","work_order":"Non Work Order","sheet_number":null},{"code":"9","date":"2016-01-07","material_code":"K0001204","name":"Thinner","specs":"HG\/HIGT GLASS","qty_act":"40","note_act":null,"reg_no":"OW001","work_order":"Non Work Order","sheet_number":null},{"code":"10","date":"2016-01-12","material_code":"K0000847","name":"Paint","specs":"no.115-312,Kansai@20 L\/can","qty_act":"20","note_act":null,"reg_no":"OA001","work_order":"Non Work Order","sheet_number":null}]}
```

And here's the result after I type something and then the error pop up :

```js
Can't get Data from DB , check your SQL Query
```

Anyone can help me please?

Thank You,

Comment: Can you show us the result of echo json_encode($response);

Comment: Here is the result of JSON before I type anything in search field :

{draw: 1, recordsTotal: 3578, recordsFiltered: 3578,…}
data
:
[{code: "1", date: "2016-01-04", material_code: "K0000285", name: "Cutting Wheel",…},…]
draw
:
1
recordsFiltered
:
3578
recordsTotal
:
3578
Here's the result after I type in search field and the error pop up : Can't get Data from DB , check your SQL Query.

Comment: can you put a good copy of that in the question.

Comment: Done. Anything else I need to do? Please let me know. I need to solve this problem. Hope you or somebody else can help.

Comment: This object is messed up. Are you getting it from print_r in php?

Comment: I don't know, I get the object from Google Chrome Developers Tools, Network to be exact.

Comment: Okay in your php file can you place var_dump(json_encode($response)); at the end. That should spit out the object on the page.

Comment: Well, done. I've placed var_dump(json_encode($response)); in the process.php file, But I'm unable to spit out the object on the process.php page because the POST variable must be sent before I access the page, the page says NO POST Query from DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the SQL you have is incorrect when aliasing a table

```
FROM mat_used_master_data = a INNER JOIN material_tools_master_data = b
```

should be

```
FROM mat_used_master_data AS a INNER JOIN material_tools_master_data AS b
```

This would make it so that your json is not created correctly. Also, you probably do not want to

```
echo "NO POST Query from DataTable";
```

Instead send an empty json object.

Comment: I change the SQL Query to what you suggested but still no luck. Still unable to make Search work..

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I made it. xD

So Here's what I've done, I change all the process.php code with this code :

process.php

```html
<?php
    /*
     * Script:    DataTables server-side script for PHP and MySQL
     * Copyright: 2010 - Allan Jardine, 2012 - Chris Wright
     * License:   GPL v2 or BSD (3-point)
     */
     
    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * Easy set variables
     */
     
    /* Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables. Use a space where
     * you want to insert a non-database field (for example a counter or static image)
     */
    $aColumns = array( 'date', 'material_code', 'name', 'specs', 'qty_act', 'note_act', 'work_order','sheet_number','reg_no');
     
    /* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
    $sIndexColumn = "code";
     
    /* DB table to use */
    $sTable = "mat_used_master_data";
     
    /* Database connection information */
    $gaSql['user']       = "root";
    $gaSql['password']   = "";
    $gaSql['db']         = "kdm";
    $gaSql['server']     = "localhost";
     
     
    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP server-side, there is
     * no need to edit below this line
     */
     
    /*
     * Local functions
     */
    function fatal_error ( $sErrorMessage = '' )
    {
        header( $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] .' 500 Internal Server Error' );
        die( $sErrorMessage );
    }
 
     
    /*
     * MySQL connection
     */
    if ( ! $gaSql['link'] = mysql_pconnect( $gaSql['server'], $gaSql['user'], $gaSql['password']  ) )
    {
        fatal_error( 'Could not open connection to server' );
    }
 
    if ( ! mysql_select_db( $gaSql['db'], $gaSql['link'] ) )
    {
        fatal_error( 'Could not select database ' );
    }
     
     
    /*
     * Paging
     */
    $sLimit = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
    {
        $sLimit = "LIMIT ".intval( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".
            intval( $_GET['iDisplayLength'] );
    }
     
     
    /*
     * Ordering
     */
    $sOrder = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
    {
        $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
            {
                $sOrder .= $aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."
                    ".($_GET['sSortDir_'.$i]==='asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc') .", ";
            }
        }
         
        $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
        if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
        {
            $sOrder = "";
        }
    }
     
     
    /*
     * Filtering
     * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
     * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
     * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
     */
    $sWhere = "";
    if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
    {
        $sWhere = "WHERE (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" )
            {
                $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
            }
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }
     
    /* Individual column filtering */
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
        {
            if ( $sWhere == "" )
            {
                $sWhere = "WHERE ";
            }
            else
            {
                $sWhere .= " AND ";
            }
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
        }
    }
     
     
    /*
     * SQL queries
     * Get data to display
     */
    $sQuery = " SELECT a.code, a.date, a.material_code, b.name, b.specs, a.qty_act, a.note_act, a.reg_no, a.work_order, a.sheet_number
        FROM mat_used_master_data AS a INNER JOIN material_tools_master_data AS b ON a.material_code = b.material_code
        $sWhere
        $sOrder
        $sLimit
    ";
    $rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );
     
    /* Data set length after filtering */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
    ";
    $rResultFilterTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );
    $aResultFilterTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultFilterTotal);
    $iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];
     
    /* Total data set length */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT COUNT(".$sIndexColumn.")
        FROM   $sTable
    ";
    $rResultTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );
    $aResultTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultTotal);
    $iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];
     
     
    /*
     * Output
     */
    /*
 $output = array(
        "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
        "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
        "aaData" => array()
    );
 */
     
    while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_array( $rResult ) )
    {
        $row = array();
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $aColumns[$i] == "version" )
            {
                /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
                $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
            else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
            {
                /* General output */
                $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
        }
        $output['aaData'][] = $row;
    }
     
    echo json_encode( $output );
?>
```

And voila! it works now. Thanks by the way for your assist @nerdlyist. I really appreciate it.